# On Flutter, how to keep login persistent by exchanging refresh token for an id token after 1 hour?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am developing a Flutter app using Firebase authentication (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-api-usage).

This is the function that refreshes the token

```
Future<void> refreshSession() async {
    final url =
        'https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?[API-KEY]';

    try {
      print(_refreshToken);
      final response = await http.post(url,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: json.encode(
              {"grant_type": "refresh_token", "refresh_token": _refreshToken}));

      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);

      if (responseData['error'] != null) {
        throw HttpException(responseData['error']['message']);
      } else {
        _token = responseData['id_token'];
        _refreshToken =
            responseData['refresh_token']; // Also save your refresh token
        _userId = responseData['user_id'];
        _expiryDate = DateTime.now()
            .add(Duration(seconds: int.parse(responseData['expires_in'])));

        notifyListeners();
        final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        final userData = json.encode({
          'token': _token,
          'refresh_token': _refreshToken,
          'userId': _userId,
          'expiryDate': _expiryDate.toIso8601String(),
        });
        prefs.setString('userData', userData);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

This getter checks if the user is within the 1 hour expiry window or else it refreshes the session - if neither of these is true, it returns null.

```
 String get token {
    if (_expiryDate != null &&
        _expiryDate.isAfter(DateTime.now()) &&
        _token != null) {
      print("Inside the 1hour loop:" + _refreshToken);
      return _token;
    } else if (_refreshToken != null) {
      print("Inside persistent login:" + _refreshToken);
      refreshSession();
      return _token;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

The problem is my getter is not getting into the RefreshSession loop at all. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using the Firebase Authentication SDK, which does this automatically? https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/firebase_auth-library.html

Comment: I went down the API route so I'd just like to keep that if I can.

Comment: Fair enough. In that case, when your step through this code in a debugger, which specific line doesn't do what you expect it to do? What are the values of all variables at that point? If you provide that type of information, it is more likely someone can see what is goign wrong.